# Get distinct types of edge in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Beginner question. How do I get the distinct types of edge in Cypher?

I know how to get all the edges in the database:

```
MATCH (a)-[r*1..1]->(b)
RETURN extract(x IN r | {rel: x})
```

And I can see that each one has a `TYPE` property. But how do I refine this to get the distinct TYPEs?

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you are looking for

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
RETURN distinct(type(r))
```

you might also use

```
call db.relationshipTypes
```

edit: if the first doesnt return anything that means you have no relationship in db, second might work only from neo4j 3.1 version on

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid the first didn't return any results, and the latter gave me `Server Error (invalid_parameter): The Cypher query is missing a "return" statement.`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If I do `MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) RETURN r` then I get thousands of results, so there are definitely relationships in the database. However, if I do `return r.type` or `return r.TYPE` I get nothing, so maybe that's the issue? I'm using Linkurious, which does show TYPE properties in the results.

Comment: you have to `return type(r)` not `return r.type`

Answer (score 1):

For any length paths you can use UNWIND and DISTINCT:

```
   MATCH p = (a)-[r*1..5]->(b)
   UNWIND relationships(p) as rel
   RETURN distinct type(rel) as type
```

Comment: @stob-- maybe add that using any variable length for depth would return a collection of relationships for the `r` alias so he understand why you have to UNWIND ;-)

Comment: Thanks - I'm afraid this didn't return any results though... is there something I can do to debug?

Comment: @Richard You want get all relationship type in database?

Answer (score 1):

The [builtin procedure](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/procedures/) `db.relationshipTypes` will return a collection of all relationship types very quickly, from cached data. For example:

```
CALL db.relationshipTypes() YIELD relationshipType
RETURN relationshipType;
```

*Prior to version 3.0.0-M05, this procedure was named `sys.db.relationshipTypes`.*